# PHP - mysql_fetch_assoc() issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to learn how to display data I select from a mysql database (phpmyadmin). My current php code consists of 2 files connect.inc.php and connecting.php:

conncet.inc.php is the file used to establish connection with the database:

```
<?php
//Varialbles
//MYSQL details
$mysql_server='localhost';
$mysql_user='root';
$mysql_user_pass='12345678';
$mysql_db='test';

//Messages
$db_conn_error='Could not connect to database';

if(mysql_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_user, $mysql_user_pass)
and mysql_select_db($mysql_db)){
echo 'Connection is ok'.'<br>';
}
else
{
echo 'Connection is not ok';
}
?>
```

while the other file (connecting.php) should display any records in the particular table called food :

```
<?php
require 'connect.inc.php';

$query = "SELECT 'food', 'calories' FROM food ORDER BY 'id'";


if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)){

    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
        $food = $query_row['food'];
        $calories = $query_row['calories'];

        echo $food . ' has '.$calories.' calories.<br>';
    }

}
else
{
echo 'Query Failed';
}
?>
```

Additional details:

- server name : localhost
- user : root
- password : 12345678
- database name : test
- table name : food
- field names : id, food, calories, healthy_unhealthy

Ths issue is that whenever i execute code in the file connecting.php i always get the following:

- Connection is ok
- food has calories calories.
- food has calories calories.

When it should say

- Connection is ok
- Pizza has 1000 calories
- Salad has 200 calories

Help is highly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance,

Joe :)

Comment: Single quote (') is used for string literals, use backticks (`) for table and column names

Comment: Did the Trick. Thanks Mark, still really green at php.

Comment: But if you're just beginning to learn PHP and MySQLi, learn to use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variable; not the old MySQL extension

Comment: @user2612009 That’s MySQL and not PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$query = "SELECT `food`,`calories` FROM `food` ORDER BY 'id'";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using single quotes (`'`) in your query

```
$query = "SELECT 'food', 'calories' FROM food ORDER BY 'id'";
```

This query will give output as:

```
food | calories
-----|---------
food | calories
food | calories
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77997/1)

Single quote (') is used for string literals. If you want to escape your column names use backticks(`) instesd.

```
$query = "SELECT `food`, `calories` FROM food ORDER BY `id`";
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77997/2)

**Note:** Please use different names for column and table name. Currently you are using  `food` as column and table name. Please avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

Use  `  instead of  '  in column and table names, like this:

```
query= "SELECT `food`, `calories` FROM `food` ORDER BY `id`";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to this without single quotes:

```
$query = "SELECT food, calories FROM food ORDER BY id";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do check your query

Try the below line and check for the error

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM food ORDER BY id") or mysql_error();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quote (') for column and table names. Use backticks(`) instead and everything will be fine. Single quotes are used for strings in php.